# One-dimensional integral equation uniquely solvable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integral-operators

I recently met a question similar to this one and I would like to post it here, because I basically found nothing:

We define the (possibly unbounded) integral operator $T:D(T) \subset C_0(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C_0(\mathbb{R})$

$$(Tf)(q):=\int_{0}^{\infty} K(q,p)f(p) dp.$$

The kernel function $K \in C_0((0,\infty) \times (0,\infty))$ (the continuous functions converging to zero) has a constant sign.

I would like to know: Are there any known non-trivial sufficient conditions such that

$$Tf=f$$ has at most one non-trivial solution (up to multiples).

Edit: I changed the ambient space to $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ which should simplify the question only and added that $K$ should have a constant sign.